# FE-Exam practice: "How many years until you're a millionaire?"

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic, finance

One of the early questions in the NCEES FE Industrial/Systems Exam study guide has a solution that I can't decipher. The question is as follows:

> Bob wants to be a millionaire. To achieve this goal, at the end of the
> year he invests $5000 each year into an account that pays 10%
> interest, compounded yearly. How many years will it take Bob to reach
> this goal?

The part I need help with is the solution to this problem, it's written bellow. I have no idea how it gets from $(\$5000)\frac{(1+0.1)^n - 1}{0.1})$ to $21 = 1.1^n$. *Can anyone provide an alternate solution or some explanation?* Thank you!

[Textbook solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h1CVw.png):

> \begin{align}
> A&=\text{uniform series of end of compounding period cash flows}\\
> &=\$5000\\
> i&=\text{annual interest rate}\\
> &=10\%\\
> n&=\text{number of compounding periods}\\
> &=\text{number of years}\\
> F&=\text{future equivalent value of a cash flow or series of cash flows}\\
> &=\$1,000,000\\
> \end{align}
>
> \begin{align}
> \$1,000,000&=(\$5000)(F/A,10\%,n)\\
> &=(\$5000)\frac{(1+0.1)^n - 1}{0.1})\\
> 21&=1.1^n\color{red}{\leftarrow}\\
> \log 21 &=n\log 1.1\\
> n&=\frac{\log 21}{\log 1.1}=31.94\text{ yr}
> \end{align}

Answer (score 2):

The $1,000,000 carries down and is equal to the right hand side of the equation in the red box. From there, use the following rearrangements:

$$1000000= 5000\Big(\cfrac{(1+0.1)^n - 1}{0.1}\Big)$$

$$\cfrac{1000000}{5000}= \cfrac{(1+0.1)^n - 1}{0.1}$$

$$\Big(\cfrac{1000000}{5000}\Big)(0.1) = (1 + 0.1)^n - 1$$

$$\Big(\cfrac{1000000}{5000}\Big)(0.1) + 1= 1.1^n$$

$$21 = 1.1^n$$

Hope that helps.

Comment: I'm not sure the OP will understand how you the first line.  Perhaps you should add a little explanation.

Comment: @saulspatz Looks fine to me. The first line is essentially the same as the line in the question just before $21 = 1.1^n.$